# Automapper map Post models to domain models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, domain-driven-design, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

I have the following model sets:

- Entities
- Domains
- Views
- Requests (Post methods)

I have the following automapper mappings:

- Entity -> domain
- Domain -> Entity
- Domain -> View

I have hard time understanding what do to with my Post models. Should they be mapped directly to domains? Should they be mapped to RequestsDomains?

What do you think?

Comment: "Entities" == objects mapped by Entity Framework ? "Domains" == domain objects ? Please clarify. In DDD, domain object creation commands are usually not automapped field to field to domain objects since that would bypass invariant enforcement. Normal constructors or Factories are used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Post models are nearly always commands in the DDD sense. If they are true commands, then your domain is responsible for enforcing invariants etc. Mapping could bypass all of those. I rarely if ever map back into a domain. You can pass a command to a handler or the command directly to the domain for any potential state changes:

```
class Invoice {
     void Handle(ApproveCommand command) {
         // Do work to approve an invoice. ApproveCommand is your Post model
     }
}
```

Comment: So if I need to add an entity from client's input, inside that Handle method you instantiate an Entity directly? 
There are properties that I can map directly, and some others can only be filled up in the Logic layer. So is that bad practice to map into Domain and ignore some of the properties, and later on fill them with values in the Core?

Comment: Yes, I instantiate directly. That code is as procedural as it possibly could be. I don't know what a logic layer is but I make that code inside the handler as dumb and obvious as possible. Think like a stored procedure. Or you can put the handler outside the domain and poof it's a domain service.